# Custom post type author query breaks site when there's no posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an issue with my custom author query that breaks the site whenever that author does not have any posts.

In author.php I have a query that's supposed to fetch posts from a custom post type. The site has multi author functionality which is why the query looks a bit weird.

I'm thinking I've made an error in the way my markup is laid out. I've tried whatever I can think of, but I'm not having any luck. If anyone can spot any problems with the loop/query I'd be very grateful.

[Not working](http://www.ostforsk.no/author/eivind/)

[Working](http://www.ostforsk.no/author/birgitta/)

```
<?php
$author_id = get_the_author_meta( 'ID' );

if ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
  rewind_posts(); //then rewind
  ?>

  <?php
  $author_details = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
  $curauth = (isset($_GET['author_name'])) ? get_user_by('slug', $author_name) : get_userdata(intval($author));
  $temp = $wp_query;
  $wp_query = null;
  $wp_query = new WP_Query();
  $wp_query->query(array(
    'post_type'=> 'publikasjoner',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
    'meta_key' => 'rapportnummer',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'DSC',
    'author_name' => $curauth->user_nicename
  )); ?>

  <h4 class="box-title">Publikasjoner</h4>
  <div class="clearfix"></div><?php

  while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

  <?php // POST TYPE ARTICLE HERE

  <?php endwhile;

  if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) { wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $wp_query ) ); }

endif;

$wp_query = null; $wp_query = $temp; ?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by breaking the site, WSOD??

Comment: @PieterGoosen I've fixed it, so it's not breaking anymore :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tested this, but did you try:

```
if ($wp_query->have_posts()) :
    while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
        // Your loop code
    endwhile;
else :
    echo wpautop( 'Sorry, no posts were found' );
endif;
```

And can you please add the WordPress tag and mention "WordPress" somewhere in your question. It will help to find the right people that can aswer your question or others with the same question.

Comment: Thanks Tober, I managed to fix it like this a few minutes ago. Guess I just needed to sleep on it. To add to that I'd also put the query and args before the `while()` and not before the `if()`